# Apex 4 error: Schema restricted or reserved

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

My spec to keep in mind:
Oracle db version: 11.1.0
platform: UNIX AIX 5
Apex Version: 4.0.1.00.03

Problem:
We are trying to created a workspace in APEX based on a schema created in the DB 'MLS'. 
once we do that it comes up with the error that the schema is restricted or reserved.

There is a patch in place but it is for the APEX version : 4.0.2. have been searching wherever google could take me and no such luck for this particular version. I have been on the OTN Discussion Forum and I have place a question there as well.

Is it possisble anybody could help me with a known patch or work-around please? Upgrading to version 4.1 - is not possible at this point in time.

Any help would be appreciated,
Melanie

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried unrestricting the schema as described in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17556_01/doc/admin.40/e15521/adm_schema.htm)?

```
EXEC APEX_040000.APEX_SITE_ADMIN_PRIVS.UNRESTRICT_SCHEMA(p_schema => 'MLS');
COMMIT;
```

This would lift the restriction for all workspaces. Alternatively, you could [add an exception](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17556_01/doc/admin.40/e15521/adm_schema.htm#CIHIHAFD) for a specific workspace:

```
BEGIN
   APEX_040000.APEX_SITE_ADMIN_PRIVS.CREATE_EXCEPTION(p_schema => 'MLS', 
                                                      p_workspace => 'YOUR_WS');
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: ,I have tried unrestricting the schema. and I have tried adding an exception as well. And it didnt work as well.

Comment: Thanks VIncent for trying to help! Some how I unedited your name from my previous comment! <sorry>

Comment: Ok your schema is not restricted, then its name is probably reserved in APEX 4.0, can you check with `APEX_04000.wwv_flow_provision.IS_RESERVED('MLS')`? Found the command in [a thread on the OTN forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2223952&tstart=0). In this thread a patch is listed (patch 12628819 on support.oracle.com)

Comment: Oh this must be the OTN thread you mentionned in your question. So I suppose it didn't help with your problem

Comment: yes that was the thread I was referring to. my question is if that patch can be applied to Apex version 4.0.1 as well, as it states that it is for version 4.0.2. Still holding on for an answer on that question...

Answer (score 1):

The final result was to upgrade to version 4.1. Though it is risky that is what the clients want. My personal solution would have been to patch 4.0.2 and apply the patch that was designed for this version. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
begin 
 apex_040200.htmldb_site_admin_privs.unrestrict_schema(p_schema => 'SCOTT');
 commit;
end;
```

Comment: Could you explain a little, say if you want your post to be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

On Apex 5 do the following:
-- Check restricted schemas 
SELECT * FROM APEX_050000.wwv_flow_restricted_schemas;
-- Unrestrict your schema
EXEC APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.UNRESTRICT_SCHEMA('OE');
-- Add your schema to your workspace
EXEC APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.ADD_SCHEMA('WORKSPACE', 'OE')
-- Don't forget to commit!
commit;